# Insert thousands of many to many links to the DB quickly

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am working on a project where I have the following scenario:

Sales-rep A may deal with customers x, y and z for products 1, 2 and 3
Sales-rep B may deal with customers w, y and z for product 1, 5 and 6

to deal with the above I have the following table structures:

SalesReps: a table with the detail of each sales rep uniquely identified by SRID
Products: a table with all the products with unique key PRID
Customers: a tabel with customer details with unique key CID

Finally I link them with a table

RepProductCustomer: with columns SRID, PRID and CID

It all works fine generally but when dealing with a company which has a lot of products and customers and sales-reps the number of rows gets really large and take very long to add using Entity Framework.

What's the most efficient way to add these entries? Can I use some sort of stored procedure or SQL command to speed this up? I have tried various EF optimisations, but there is just too much data to be inserted on some occasions and the user has to wait for a very long time for the request to complete.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How exactly do you insert link rows? In a row-by-row manner?

Comment: Sounds like you have a source of data (text,other db or csv) and you load the data into your EF classes and then save them using Save method in EF, Right?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes. So basically I loop through each rep for each product  for each customer and the the SRID, PRID and CID to the RepProductCustomer entity. After all the records have been added I call SaveChanges. The nested looping itself takes a very long time and I am wondering if there is a quicker way to add these. It need not be via EF. I am happy to use a stored proc if there is somehow a fast way of editing these.

Comment: To give you some context, we are getting the reps to submit their info into the system .So for reps who deal with a large number of products or clients end up having to wait really long for this process to finish. One solution I was thinking of was to store the information submitted by the reps in some sort of raw CSV format first and then use a scheduler to process it in the background. But I would really prefer to avoid the headache if  possible and speed up the entry of the data in the database.

Comment: @FLICKER No I am not loading the data from a CSV file in this instance. This is more a form which asks the reps to select the product they deal with and the clients they deal with. They then click submit and I run a nested loop to add these to the Entity.

Comment: Where do you get the information about which SRID, PRID and CID are connected? How do you know what combinations to insert?

Comment: @IvanStarostin The sales reps are sent an email with a link. They click the link which takes them to a page which has a three step wizard. 

Step 1: personal information such as name etc are collected. This information is used to create the record for the sales rep.

Step 2: specify the rpoducts you works with. Here they select form a list of products, all the products they work with. There is also a select all is they work on all of them.

Step 3: Select the customers you work with. Similar to Step 2 here they select all the customers they deal with.

Comment: Finally they click the submit button and all the information is submitted to the server. This information is used to by the server to first create the rep record and tehn link them to the channels and agencies.

Comment: If looping through entities takes too much time, I would try to push all selected values via xml/csv directly to stored proc and to insert all values by a single insert. But this approach will require validation on server side.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thanks. I was thinking along the same lines. I will try using a stored proc that parses the CSV data and then performs a bulk insert.Will mention my findings here in case some one else has the same issue.

Comment: I tried using a stored procedure as well but it started timing out as well. For now I have made it so that the admin processes the large payloads one by one and leaves them to process over long a duration of time. Since most of the cases are not heavy duty data, for now we have decided to tackle the big ones on a one by one basis. So basically this is jsut a temp solution and I am still looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, EF optimization you try will not work since the real issue in your scenario is the number of database round trip performed (one per record) which make the SaveChanges method very slow.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

BulkSaveChanges allow to save using Bulk Operations and reduce database round trip.

All associations and inheritance are supported.

```
// Upgrade SaveChanges performance with BulkSaveChanges
var context = new CustomerContext();
// ... context code ...

// Easy to use
context.BulkSaveChanges();

// Easy to customize
context.BulkSaveChanges(operation => operation.BatchSize = 1000);
```